# get the items in the related list through query

Tags: apex, soql, query

How can I get the items in my related list in query? `Teacher_Set__c` has related list for `Student__c` and `Teacher__c`. I tried this query:

```
 for (teacher_Set__c tset : [Select Id, teacher__r.Id, student__r.Id, name from teacher_set__c WHERE name = : teachers]){}
```

But it throws the error:

> Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship 'teacher__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name

Comment: whats the data you want here ?

Comment: What is the error?  Do you want the parent records of `teacher_set__c` or the children of `teacher_set__c`?

Comment: When you have an error, it is generally in your best interest to tell us its content if you want us to be able to help you. We're not psychic. We can guess, but making us guess is not going to yield good results (or a positive reaction as far as votes go). It demonstrates a lack of effort on your part at a very basic level.

Comment: i need to get the items in the related list both teacher and student

Comment: That's definitely an improvement. I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 2):

`teacher__r` and `student__r` reference parent records, but that's not the correct syntax.  You want either `teacher__c` to get the Id of the parent record, or you want `teacher__r.xxx` to get the value of field `xxx` from the parent.

If you want children of `teacher_set__c` you'll need to find the name of the child relationship and do a sub-query/.

Comment: Teacher__r.id will work just fine if the lookup field is named teacher__c although it is not best practice and is necessary. Based on the Op answer though Teacher__c is many on a one-to-many related object and not a lookup